# Updating arrays from file, with verification in C

Tags: c, arrays, file

Suppose I have a program (a game, to be specific) with an array of char
called `board` and with 256 elements. If I wanted to update that array
from a save file which is on the disk, and also verify that no illegal
characters are being written to the array, I can do one of a few things:

1. Verify everything first. If no errors, read file into array.
2. Create backup copy of old array. Write into array while checking.
    If there is an error, display a message and copy the backup array
    into the real array. Otherwise, just return.
3. Create new array. Write into new array while checking. If there is
    an error, display a message and don't do anything else. If there is
    no error, copy the new array into the real array.

I realize I may have used some extremely unclear language with points 2
and 3, so I'll have some examples:

## Approach 1

```
void load_and_verify(char board[], const char *file)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    verify_board(board);

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        int ch = fgetc(fp);

        if (ch == EOF) {
            return;
        }

        board[i] = ch;
    }
}

void verify_board(char board[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        if (!is_valid_board_char(ch)) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

## Approach 2

```
void load_and_verify(char board[], const char *file)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    char backup_board[256];
    memcpy(backup_board, board, 256);

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        int ch = fgetc(fp);

        if (ch == EOF) {
            return;
        }

        if (!is_valid_board_char(ch)) {
            memcpy(board, backup_board, 256);
            return;
        }

        board[i] = ch;
    }
}
```

## Approach 3

```
void load_and_verify(char board[], const char *file)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    char new_board[256];

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        int ch = fgetc(fp);

        if (ch == EOF) {
            return;
        }

        if (!is_valid_board_char(ch)) {
            return;
        }

        new_board[i] = ch;
    }

    memcpy(board, new_board, 256);
}
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with approach three, as there is no need to backtrack in case of error and produces easier to read code.

I would also recommend that you read the whole file content in a single call (use fread or fgets instead of fgetc), this will improve the performance a lot.

Finally, no matter which approach you use, **remember to fclose before returning**.

Answer (score 2):

Approach 1 is subject to failure because the file content was changed between the time you checked and the time you re-read it into the program.  This is a TOCTOU (time of check, time of use) vulnerability and should be avoided.

Either of approaches 2 and 3 can be used — for many purposes, they're equivalent.  I'd probably go with option 3 as there is less recovery needed if the data from the file is faulty.  With approach 2, you save the current (good) state, find a bad state, and have to copy the saved state back to recreate the good (and throw away the saved copy).  With approach 3, you just throw away the new faulty state.